# Facebook checkins on MKMapView

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, mkmapview

I am working on an app in which I've Facebook login after successful login a `UIViewController` with a `MKMapView` will appear. I just want to get all the checkins an put annotations on the `MKMapView`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to ask the user's permission to be able to access Checkins at login. After that you can use "https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=..." to get all the check ins by the logged in user. To access a friend's check ins use "https://graph.facebook.com/[Friend's userID]/checkins?access_token=...", which will return all the check ins of that friend that are accessible to the logged in user.

For a look at the Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

For how to use the Facebook SDK to call these APIs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/

Comment: thanks but my main question is how can I put those check ins onto `MKMapView`

Comment: In response to the correct Checkin API, you will receive the checkin objects "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/". There is a "place" parameter in the response which in turn holds the latitude/longitude parameters.

Comment: All you have to do is extract this information, create a custom class that adopts the MKAnnotation protocol, store this location information into the objects of that custom class and simply pass the array of custom objects to the MKMapView's addAnnotations: method. For reference: "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html". Hope this helps